# Trouble Returning Multiple Tags (CSV) in One Column from Many-to-Many table

Tags: php, mysql

**Task Context:**

- I'm building a website to categorize data from a sample db of Movies
  (kinda like Plex/ IMDB).
- Each actor in the db has a summary page which lists their film credits (the movies they have starred in).
- These movies are displayed in a [Bootstrap Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BNPL.png)  and I'm able to successfully retrieve the data from the corresponding table with a foreach.
- I have recently implemented a tagging system (along with necessary additional tables &  relationships) and would like to add to my current Bootstrap table in the form of an additional column and to display these tags separated by a comma.

**Database Tables & Relationships:**

- I'm attaching a [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyYGS.png) of my database schema.

**Solutions**

**Attempt #1**

- Ending the foreach at Column 5 and creating a new query (joining tags
  to movie_tags)
- Needed to use an IF statement to force the query to return
  corresponding values
- Output is correct (3 Records) but results are [concatenated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB0H1.png).

```
<?php include 'conn.php';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE actor_1 ='Clint Eastwood' OR actor_2 ='Clint Eastwood'");
$movies = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
    
    <table id="displaymovies" class="table display table-sortable table-hover table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Film ID</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Release Year</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Movie Title</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Movie Studio</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Actor/Actress</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Tags</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
    
           <?php foreach($movies as $database) : ?>
           <tr>
              <td><?=$database['movie_id']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['release_year']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['movie_title']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['movie_studio']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['actor_1']; ?></td>
              <?php endforeach; ?> 
          <td>                        
     <?php include_once("conn.php");
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tags JOIN movies_tags ON movies_tags.tag_id=tags.tag_id";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                
        if ($row["movie_id"] == 1) {
        echo $row["tag_title"];
           }
        }
        ?>
          </td> 
            </tr>
              </tbody>
                </table>
```

**Attempt #2**

- Ending the foreach at Column 5 and creating a new foreach
- Output is correct (3 records) but these records are created in [individual columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aClgR.png), rather than being returned in the one column.

```
<?php include 'conn.php';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE actor_1 ='Clint Eastwood' OR actor_2 ='Clint Eastwood'");
$movies = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
    
    <table id="displaymovies" class="table display table-sortable table-hover table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Film ID</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Release Year</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Movie Title</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Movie Studio</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Actor/Actress</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Tags</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
    
           <?php foreach($movies as $database) : ?>
           <tr>
              <td><?=$database['movie_id']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['release_year']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['movie_title']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['movie_studio']; ?></td>
              <td><?=$database['actor_1']; ?></td>
              <?php endforeach; ?> 
    
<?php include 'conn.php';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tags JOIN movies_tags ON movies_tags.tag_id=tags.tag_id");
$tags= $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

             <?php foreach($tags as $database2) : ?>

              <td><?=$database2['Tag_Title']; ?>
                  <?php endforeach; ?> 
             </td>

                                
             </tr>
               </tbody>
                  </table>
```

**Other Efforts Made**

- **GROUP_CONCAT:** I came across many posts and articles referring to Group_Concat with DISTINCT and SEPERATE being the solution. I unfortunately could not figure out how to get that to work.
- **Aggregation of Arrays:** I also came across posts suggesting I could get the desired output by aggregating the arrays and combining the foreach's, I couldn't get this to work but I assume it would also output the additional columns as per Attempt #2.
- I'm pretty new to all of this and sure I'm overcomplicating things, hoping there is a simple solution.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read through this.

Comment: As an Aside: Question... what if a movie has 1 or more than 6 actors? As a movie can have many actors, you'll need to look at using a movie_actors join table with movie_id and actor_id.

Comment: I think this question is unnecessarily complicated. The core problem is that you cannot query (or transform the query results with php) in an expected format. Bottstrap and html are not relevant for this question. In mysql group_concat() should do the trick based on what you described. Can you pls share the exact query you tried and share what results you received vs what results you expected to see?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw - Yes, agreed. Originally, I had all of the "tags" in individual columns in the movies table; i.e. Tag 1, Tag 2 etc up to Tag 10. I moved this information out into a seperate many-to-many and will need to do the same for the actors section at somepoint.

Comment: @Shadow - Yes, i hard a difficult time setting it out, comes from the fact I barely know what I am talking about. Sorry for that. The exact query I ran is in the code snippet above, if you refer to the Bootstrap table diagram - the actual result I am getting is line 3 (Spaghetti WesternActionSergio Leone)

Comment: Of course you get them all one after the other, if all you do is `echo $row["tag_title"];` inside a loop. If you want any separator between them, you would have to output that in that place as well.

Comment: I cannot see group concat anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are many ways to get desired results.

One query for all movies with `Clint Eastwood` with their tags combined as coma-separated list.

```sql
SELECT m.*,
      GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_title ORDER BY t.tag_title SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags_list
FROM `movies` AS m 
JOIN `movies_tags` AS m2t ON (m2t.movie_id = m.movie_id )
JOIN `tags` AS t ON (t.tag_id = m2t.tag_id)
WHERE m.actor_1 = 'Clint Eastwood' OR m.actor_2 = 'Clint Eastwood'
```

Here, you ask for all movies from `movies` and all *associated* tags from `tags` for that movie (via junction table `movies_tags`). All tags should be ordered by `tag_title` and combined in one row with `,`  as `SEPARATOR`

So you'll need only one foreach.

```
<?php foreach($movies as $database) : ?>

<tr>
    <td><?=$database['movie_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$database['release_year']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$database['movie_title']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$database['movie_studio']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$database['actor_1']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$database['tags_list']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It should work, but it's not flexible.
As soon as you need more, it would be too complicated/cumbersome (like clickable tags to navigate to a page with ALL movies associated with this particular tag)
Also, if this movie **has no tags assigned yet**, it will simply not be selected.

A much better approach would be to iterate over all movies (in your case - all movies with `Clint Eastwood`) Then ask for all tags for this particular movie (`movie_id`) and if there are any, iterate over those.

```
<?php include_once 'conn.php';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE actor_1 ='Clint Eastwood' OR actor_2 ='Clint Eastwood'");
$movies = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <!-- iterate over all movies -->
    <?php foreach($movies as $movie_row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $movie_row['movie_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie_row['release_year']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie_row['movie_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie_row['movie_studio']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie_row['actor_1']; ?></td>
        

        <?php 
        // include_once 'conn.php'; I dont think you should include it once again. but uncomment if it doesn't work.
        // You need to bind a movie_id from $movie_row['movie_id'] to this query. So just $conn->query("...") won't work. 

        // $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tags JOIN movies_tags ON (movies_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id AND movies_tags.movie_id = ?)"); // won't work

        // Sorry, I don't know whats inside your conn.php and how it works, but I assume you use mysqli and $conn is just an instance of new mysqli(....) 
        // If so, try this


        $tags_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tags JOIN movies_tags ON (movies_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id AND movies_tags.movie_id = ?)");
        $tags_stmt->bind_param('d', (int)$movie_row['movie_id']); // 'd' stands for digit, since $movie_row['movie_id'] is a digit
        $tags_stmt->execute();    
        //$tags= $tags_stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $tags = $tags_stmt->fetch_assoc();
        $has_tags = !empty($tags);
        ?>

        
        <td>
           <!-- if there're tags, then iterate ...
            <?php if($has_tags) : ?>    
                <?php foreach($tags as $tag_row) : ?>
                    <?php echo $tag_row['tag_title']; ?>&nbsp;
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            <?php else: ?>
                no tags yet...
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- some housekeeping -->
            <?php $tags_stmt->close(); ?>
        </td>
                
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. Code is untested!